# SailsJS and global functions, variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Just wondering how can I have an object which is accessible everywhere models, controllers etc in SailsJS. I need this mostly for some utility functions which I use quite often. Do you think that's a good idea?

EDIT: What's the recommended way to do this

Comment: then make a global utils object or use require or hide it as a property of another global.

Comment: whats the recommended way to do this, is it just go into bootstrap.js and do: global.utils = require('lib/utils'); ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [documentation for Services](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services) in the Sails docs.  They sound like exactly what you're looking for--custom modules that are globalized for use throughout your app.

Comment: I tried creating a _.js service that loaded in a newer version of lodash into SailsJS, and it failed - likely because I don't know how to load all functions from lodash into a module.exports = { ... } notation.

It would be nice to see an example of globalizing something like lodash, especially that did not conflict with SailsJS' v2.x version of lodash.

Comment: You should be able to just turn off the default Lodash global using the [globals configuration](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/globals).  If you wanted to globalize your own version using Sails services, you can just set the service like `module.exports  = require('lodash')`.

Comment: Thanks sgress454. I did try that, creating _.js then lodash.js, but it fails in sails-build-dictionary/index.js line 120:

    module.identity = module.identity.toLowerCase();
TypeError 'undefined is not a function'.

Comment: Ah, that's because Lodash has a method called `identity`, and the module loader in Sails expects `identity` to be an optional value that you can supply in order to change the "identity" of the module (not used for services, but important for models).  As long as you don't plan on using Lodash's `identity` method, you can just do `module.exports = require('lodash'); delete module.exports.identity` and it should work.